# Get road polyline from road polyline buffer layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, merge, spatial-join, road

I need to reverse the action of buffer tool. I had two polyline layers from two different sources with different attributes for a section of a city, that I needed to combine. In order to spatially combine those, I made created a buffer of one of those and then used that to spatially join. Now the joined attributes are in the buffer layer and I need to get the polylines for the that layers. I couldnt do the other way around ( join the features to the lines instead of the buffer) because of the characteristics of the layers.

Is there any way to convert buffer layer to road polyline layer? I tried spatially joining the buffer layer to the original road layer,but the files are large and the "memory not enough" error pops on.

or is there an any simpler way to merge attributes of two road polyline layers?

Comment: Why couldn't you overlay roads_v1 with the buffer of roads_v2? Identity or intersect would (should) work for this case... you'd end up with a few dags where buffers overlay or the road lines extend outside roads buffer though. Can you give an example of what you have? It might be that a spatial join to the centroid of the lines from one class to the other then attribute join back by FID would suit your needs better.

Comment: Intersect worked, so did the just joining the two tables. I just realized that there were some 'dags' in the previous step, which messed up my result, and I was only checking on the final result. Thank you Michael Miles-Stimson.

Comment: That post was the answer to one of my questions. Thanks @artwork21

Comment: If you have more than one question then, as per the [Tour], always ask each separately as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool in ArcGIS called **Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline (Cartography)**. You need the Advanced license for this tool. Perhaps the **Merge Divided Roads (Cartography)** tool would also work for this task.

Comment: There's still *a lot* of manual work cleaning up intersections with the Collapse Dual Lines tool, the magnitude of the task increases with the network complexity and exactly how discernible the centreline is from the buffer of unknown size.